# Ng2SearchPipeModule filter causing error: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'x.component'

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular-pipe, ng2-bootstrap

I have implemented a filter/search functionality on tables in Angular 6. I'm using [this ng-2-search-filter library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter).

The functionality works perfectly in the front-end, and causes no console errors.

When I run an `ng build "--prod"` the library is causing build errors in the output, everywhere I have used the filter.

**Error:**

> Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'x.component'.

I've imported the library in the `app.module.ts` appservices and @ngModule imports.

The library is also in the `package.json` as version `"ng2-search-filter": "^0.4.7"`.

The input for the filter on the html is as follows:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filter">
```

and used in the *ngFor as follows:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items| filter:filter};">
```

The only solutions I can find are in relation to the RxJS filter.
I've imported the library individually into each component that uses filter, but that has no impact.

Comment: is there a typo check **`<tr *ngFor="let item of items | filter: filter">`** and suggest you use a different ngModel value like `[(ngModel)]="customFilter"`, because  `filter: filter` might create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the error lay in the component, I didn't initialize any variable 'filter', didn't realize I should have as no errors were thrown.

```
public filter: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
Just select 'save all' and re run your code. You will not get that error.